Explication of output of DIABLO.cv function (rvaidememoire package) output
I created diablo model using mixOmics package and i used DIABLO.cv function to see the validation of the model and i found this result :
Cross validation
Model: DIABLO
5-fold validation
Validation repeated 10 times
3 components
Classification criterion: centroids distance
Mean (standard error) classification error rate (%): 58.7 (0.13)
Can someone tell me me what does 58.7 value  and (0.13) value mean , and if the model created is predectible or no and how can i improve the model
Thank you

Your classifier has an error rate and standard error of 58.7 (0.13). As for how to improve your model, it's off-topic on SO.
